# BitcoinCash кошелек Electron Cash

Tags: база-данных, bitcoin, криптовалюта

Какую Базу данных использует кошелек Electron Cash 3.1.9 (Валюта: BitcoinCash)?

Comment: Никакую. Он напрямую записывает/читает блокчейн в виде файлов.

Answer (score 3):

никакую базу не использует. можете сканировать весь репозиторий и убедиться в этом

https://github.com/fyookball/electrum/blob/master/contrib/requirements/requirements.txt